# Specific object selection without index

Tags: java, arrays, oop

What I'm trying to do is iterate through an `ArrayList` with object type `Leerling`, which has 2 attributes `cijfer` and `naam`. I want to make it possible to find the object by its `naam` attribute and then change its `cijfer` attribute with the second parameter, this is what I've come up with so far (I know it's not much).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

*Ps; deLeerlingen = Arraylist with types Leerling*

```java
public void wijzigCijfer(String nm, double nweCijfer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < deLeerlingen.size(); i++){
        if (deLeerlingen.contains(nm)) {
                
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `Leerling` class, but cant seem to call the setter..

```java
public class Leerling {
    private String naam;
    private double cijfer;

    public Leerling(String nm){
        naam = nm;
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public double getCijfer() {
        return cijfer;
    }

    public void setCijfer(double cf){
        cijfer = cf;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Leerling{" +
            "naam='" + naam + '\'' +
            ", cijfer=" + cijfer +
        '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Using set Methods ?

Comment: You mean `if(deLeerlingen.get(i).getNaam().equals(nm)){deLeerlingen.get(i).setCijfer(nweCijfer);}`? A for-each loop may work better for you here.

Comment: Can u tell us Leerling class too please?

Comment: You should use a hashmap if your naam is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With set methods you can change object attribute values so going back to the source this is what we need

```
 public void setCijfer(double cf){
        this.cijfer = cf;
    }
```

Now in the main class we go in the first if condition by checking every value on the list if it equals the name then it's true and it changes the value

```
  public void wijzigCijfer(String nm, double nweCijfer) {
        for (int i = 0; i < deLeerlingen.size(); i++){
            if (deLeerlingen.get(i).getNaam().equals(nm){
                    deLeerlingen.get(i).setCijfer(nweCijfer);
                
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `public static List<Leerling>` for that

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Leerling {
    private String naam;
    private double cijfer;

    public Leerling(String naam, double cijfer) {
        this.naam = naam;
        this.cijfer = cijfer;
    }
    public String toString () {
        return "Leerling{" +
                "naam='" + naam + '\'' +
                ", cijfer=" + cijfer +
                '}';
    }

    public static List<Leerling> set(List<Leerling> list, String naam, double cijfer) {
        return list.stream().map(x -> {
            if (x.naam.equals(naam)) x.cijfer = cijfer;
            return x;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Leerling> leerlings = new ArrayList<>() {{
            add(new Leerling("1", 1.0));
            add(new Leerling("1", 2.0));
            add(new Leerling("2", 3.0));
            add(new Leerling("3", 4.0));
            add(new Leerling("4", 5.0));
        }};
        System.out.println(leerlings);
        System.out.println(Leerling.set(leerlings, "1", 5));
    }
}
```